# Cannot fetch data from Sanity.io -- Unable to parse entire expression -

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I am working on React App, nothing much in it a basic website.

I followed the docs from Sanity about creating the blog. I have used Sanity earlier and back then it was working fine on other project.

The query in the VISION section is returning vale. And i think the problem is with the client file. Still not sure

Client.js :

```js
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";

export default sanityClient({
  projectId: "the project key", // find this at manage.sanity.io or in your sanity.json
  dataset: "production", // this is from those question during 'sanity init'
  useCdn: false,
  apiVersion: "v2021-10-21",
});
```

App.js file :

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import sanityClient from "./client.js";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [petData, setPetData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type == 'pet'\]{
        name,
        }
        }`
      )
      .then((data) => setPetData(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {petData.map((pet, index) => (
        <p>{pet.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

And then when I run the app
I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBGDT.png)

I have tried a fresh react app as well, same result :(

Comment: The passed query string seems to be malformed: ``*[_type == 'pet'] { name }``.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error due to the comma appended after the last bracket of the query, i.e

```
groq`
 *[_type == 'page' 
  && !(_id in path('drafts.**')) 
  && slug.current == $slug][0] {
    _id,
  },  // This comma at the end of the query was the problem
`,
```

[image: unable to parse entire expression]

Resolution:

```
groq`
 *[_type == 'page' 
  && !(_id in path('drafts.**')) 
  && slug.current == $slug][0] {
    _id,
  }  // This comma removed
`,
```

Comment: Talk about an obscure error! Got the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You write the'}' in side a string just write the last '}' outside the string

useEffect(() => {
sanityClient
.fetch(
`*[_type == 'pet'\]{ name, }`
}
)
.then((data) => setPetData(data));
}, []);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).